# C++ inheritance and assignment operator

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading, assignment-operator, crtp

I am using CRTP to implement a C++ feature.

Now I've faced a situation like this.

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
    char a;

    T operator+(const T& other){
        T t;
        t.a = a + other.a;
        return t;
    }
};

struct B : A<B>{

};

struct C : B {
    C& operator=(const C& other){
        a = other.a;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    C c1,c2,c3;
    c3 = c1 + c2;
    return 0;
}
```

This code does not compile saying `no viable overloaded=`

How can I resolve the issue without adding any code to `struct A` and `struct B`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create the assign operator which takes `B` as reference:

```
struct C : B {
    C& operator=(const C& other){
        return *this = static_cast<const B&>(other);
    }

    C& operator=(const B& other){
        a = other.a;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Short explanation why you need this (I hope I am not wrong):

The `+ operator` returns a `B` reference as `B` is the template parameter, not `C`. So ignoring the `+` there would be an assignment `C = B` which is not possible. To be clear, you would not need your first assignment operator to run your code.

Maybe also this is clearer and better:

```
struct C : B {
    B& operator=(const B& other){
        a = other.a;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Now your assignment operator takes `B` as input and output.

Answer (score 1):

You also have the possibility to overload the `operator+` for the `C class` to allow the `c1 + c2` code to return a `C` object instead of a `B`object (as it currently does due to the `operator+` defined in the `B` class). In this way, you obtain a `C` object as a result of `c1+c2` that may be assigned using the defined `operator=` in class `C`.

For instance, add this function to the `C class` like the following:

```cpp
C& operator+(const C& other){
        // for example add the two operands' characters
        this->a += other.a;
        return *this;
    }
```

Beware though of the idea behind your choice as it may compile but not do what you would like it to do.

Overloading `+` or `=` may depend on what you would like to do with your code and the type you would like to obtain from the operation `c1+c2`.